# how to convert str to int? int() and float() won't work

Tags: python, python-requests-html

[image]I got some data from requests-html module and want to do calculation with it but won't work. It is a 'str' type and I tried converting it to int by using int() neither do float() work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide an [mcve]

Comment: Again me complaining... Posting an Image of your code is not providing an [mcve] Please do not just post an image of your code but write it here.

Answer (score 1):

first replace the ","

```
price1bed = price1bed.replace(",","")
```

then parse to a float

```
price1bed_float = float(price1bed)
```

lastly to int (if you want)

```
price1bed_int = int(price1bed_float)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a non numeric character in your string "1,656.00" - specifically the "," - float() and int() are failing to convert. So all you have to do is take out the ",".

You could replace it like this:

```
s = "1,656.00"
s = s.replace(',','')
s_float = float(s)
```

That's what I'd do

Answer (score 0):

As @ Pythonista said, you need to remove ","

```
 price1bed=int(price1bed.replace(',',''))
```